# Cannot get an object to `save()` from inside a loop

Tags: r, save

Example

```
x <- data.frame(x = rnorm(5e5))

save("x", file="x.Rda")
```

This correctly creates a relatively large file, 3.7Mb.

But, if I try to save multiple objects in a loop (example uses just one object):

```
for (i in "x") save(i, file="x.Rda")
```

This incorrectly creates a file that is only 67 bytes, and when loaded, is simply vector `i` with element "x".

What I have tried and what does not work:

```
for (i in "x") save(i, file="x.Rda", envir = .GlobalEnv)   # 67 byte file
for (i in "x") save(get(i), file="x.Rda")                       # object ‘get(i)’ not found
for (i in "x") save(get(i), file="x.Rda", envir = .GlobalEnv)   # object ‘get(i)’ not found
for (i in "x") save(get(i, envir = .GlobalEnv), file="x.Rda")   # object ‘get(i, envir = .GlobalEnv)’ not found
```

Comment: depending on what you are doing you do not need to save objects in a loop and you can just list all the objects and save it to one rda file. also you are overwriting x.Rda every time in the loop and it won't save a new file

Comment: @Mike I need them as separate files.

Comment: @Mike example I provided uses just one element, but with multiple, the file names would be specified, e.g. as `paste0(i, ".Rda")`

Comment: Use `for (i in "x") save(list=i, file=paste0(i, ".Rda"))`. Use the `list=` param if you want to pass object names as character values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with the preferred `saveRDS`. From the help page

> **Note**
> For saving single R objects, `saveRDS()` is mostly preferable to `save()`, notably because of the functional nature of `readRDS()`, as opposed to `load()`.

```r
x <- data.frame(x = rnorm(5e5))
obj_names <- ls(pattern = "x", envir = .GlobalEnv)

for(i in obj_names) {
  fl_name <- paste0(i, ".Rda")
  saveRDS(get(i, envir = .GlobalEnv), file = fl_name)
}

y <- readRDS("x.Rda")
identical(x, y)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I actually preferred `save()` over `saveRDS()`, because with the functional nature of `readRDS()` I would have to load multiple objects like `obj1 <- readRDS("obj1.Rda")`, `obj2 <- readRDS("obj2.Rda")`, etc... not sure there is an elegant way to load many objects (keeping the names), as there is with `load()`.

Comment: Also, notwithstanding the differences between `readRDS()` and `load()`, it's a bit baffling that `saveRDS()` and `save()` do not work the same way with regard to environment/scope.